# Problem using vpython where localhost opens but keeps forever blank

Tags: python, vpython

I have installed vpython from the terminal using pip install vpython, and it installed successfully. I am using python 3.7.2. 
When I write "import vpython as vp" a Microsoft Edge window opens called localhost:53184.
Then I write "vp.box()" or "vp.sphere()" and it does nothing, but I expect from what I am reading online that the box/sphere should appear on that Edge window opened by vpython.

Am I doing something wrong or is it due to the installation or the version of my python package?

Comment: Did you write the import statement in IDLE's Shell or standard interactive Python in a Windows console.  If you do both, is there any difference in the outcome and behavior?  (I expect that there should not be any difference, and hence that the python-idle tag should be removed.)

Comment: No, there's not any difference, so tag removed.

Comment: That should work, whether from a terminal or from many IDEs (as described at vpython.org). I don't know what is meant by "tag removed".